# Error in fresh installation of WordPress 3.4.2 on one server and running fine on other server

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am experiencing a strange error, I have two installations of WordPress Version 3.4.2 on two different servers (hosting & domains are different). As I am installing same version of WordPress on both servers but it shows me JS errors on one server as shown in below screenshot

[image: error console]

I compared the file shown in above error and figured out that there are some extra slashes that are creating the issue, please see below screenshots.

- **File from WP instance having no error:**

[image: no error]

- **File from WP instance that is having issue:**

[image: error]

Can someone tell me why some extra slashes are being added (those are creating error)? Is this a server related issue, some virus or something else & any solution to this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Those slashes look like escape characters for double quotes. Try checking everything in settings again: character encoding, language, editor configuration, etc. I am just guessing.

Comment: The only time I've seen that is when [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) is on in the php.ini file (it was used to protect against SQL injection and has since been deprecated). And since WP uses php to pull in the JS you need it may be adding in the extra slashes. Try turning off magic_quotes and see if that helps.

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA - You beat me to it! Foiled again!

Comment: I found a workaround, I replaced echo $out with echo str_replace("\\", "", $out); at second last line of public_html/wp-admin/load-scripts.php

Comment: but I know that is a bad approach.  Let me mess with php.ini

Comment: echo str_replace("\\", "", $out); fixed issue for inclusion of one file but for others there are still many issues.

Comment: If the php.ini route is difficult or impossible, then an .htaccess solution may be available (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)), though I don't know WP well enough to advise which directory's .htaccess would need to be added/modified.

Comment: Fixed!!! There was mod_security issue for the domain name, which is now excluded for the domain name.